# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userCreateForm' available as request attribute

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have some form for a user creating:

```
                <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/create" method="post" modelAttribute="userCreateForm" autocomplete="off">
                    <table class="b-table table table-striped">
                        <tbody>

                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.FirstName"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input type="text" path="firstName" cssClass="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.LastName"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input type="text" path="lastName" cssClass="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.Role"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:select path="userRole" cssClass="form-control">
                                        <form:options items="${roles}"/>
                                    </form:select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.Email"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input type="text" path="email" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off"/><span><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/></span> 
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.Password"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <form:input type="password" path="password" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off"/><span></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.Pictire"/></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" name="file" cssClass="form-control"/><span></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
                        <spring:message code="UI.Labels.User.Submit"/>
                    </button>

                </form:form>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
public String createPage(Model model, Principal principal, Locale locale) {
    final User loggedUser = getLoggedUser();

    User userCreateForm = new User();
    model.addAttribute("userCreateForm", userCreateForm);
    //model.addAttribute("roles", Utils.localizedRoles(loggedUser.getUserRole(), messageSource, locale));
    model.addAttribute("roles", systemRoleService.findAll());
    return "user/create";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(
                     @ModelAttribute User userForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model,
        Locale locale,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "user/create";
    }
    try {
        userForm.setPassword(Utils.bcrypt(userForm.getPassword()));
        userForm.setLogin(userForm.getEmail());

        userService.create(userForm);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", messageSource.getMessage("UI.Messages.User.CreatedSuccess", null, locale));
    } catch (ResourceException ue) {
        final User loggedUser = getLoggedUser();
        final List<String> failures = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String m : ue.getMessages()) failures.add( messageSource.getMessage(m, null, locale) );
        model.addAttribute("failures", failures);
        model.addAttribute("userCreateForm", userForm);
        model.addAttribute("roles", Utils.localizedRoles(loggedUser.getUserRole(), messageSource, locale));
        return "user/create";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

If I don't select any roles - it works fine, but save user without roles.
When I select a userRole at the .jsp and press 'Save' - I have an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userCreateForm' available as request attribute
```

Please, help me to solve this issue.
Could you tell me what is wrong, please?

**if I've selected a role, then in the @ModelAttribute I get SystemRole object instead User.... Why?**

Now I got a new error:

```
Field error in object 'userCreateForm' on field 'userRole': rejected value [6]; codes [typeMismatch.userCreateForm.userRole,typeMismatch.userRole,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [userCreateForm.userRole,userRole]; arguments []; default message [userRole]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'userRole'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ru.test.jpa.SystemRole] for property 'userRole[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

In the User object the filed 'userRole' - is List.
How can I get List of selected roles from the jsp?

---

I have added a converter

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.test.jpa.SystemRole;

@Component("userRoleConverter")
public class UserRoleConverter implements Converter<String, SystemRole> {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceService<SystemRole> systemRoleService;


    @Override
    public SystemRole convert(String id)  {
        return systemRoleService.findOne(Long.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

and registered it in the sprint-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="converters">
            <beans:ref bean="userRoleConverter"/>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I still get the same error.
What is wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try to use logs (or at least `Sytem.err.println` to control what path you use in controller when you select a role - I suspect there is an error ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, path is correct, BUT if I've selected a role, then in the `@ModelAttribute` I get SystemRole object instead User.... :(

Comment: You are binding to a object named `userForm` not `userCreateForm`. When using `@ModelAttribute` and not explicitly assigning a name to it it will take the name of the method argument, in this case `userForm`. Either change the paramater name or explicitly name the argument inside the `@ModelAttribute` annotation. Basically as soon as you have an error your `userCreateForm` object is gone and a `userForm` is suddenly available.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I've changed my code and now I get a new error. Look at this, please (I've added it to my question).

Answer (score 0):

The most relevant part of the error message is : `Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ru.test.jpa.SystemRole] for property 'userRole[0]'`.

You did not show `User` class, but because of the error, I assume that `userRole` is a collection or an array of `SystemRole`. You can either use a wrapper class as form object that has a setter accepting a collection of Strings and generates the roles, something like :

```
class UserWrapper {
    class User user = new User();

    // delegates for setters and getters omitted for breivety
    public void setStrUserRole(List<String> strRole) {
        role = new List<SystemRole>();
        for (String str: strRole) {
            // build role r form its String representation
            role.add(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can create a `Converter<String, SystemRole>` and register it to the `DefaultFormattingConversionService` used by Spring.

If you use XML configuration, you can register a new converter that way :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"
      id="conversionService"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
      p:targetObject-ref="conversionService" p:targetMethod="addConverter">
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="java.lang.Class">java.lang.String</value>
            <value type="java.lang.Class">ru.test.jpa.SystemRole</value>
            <ref bean="userRoleConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Because you only want to *add* a new converter, not replace the whole bunch of default Spring converters.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for you help, but I still have a problem. Help me please, this is last step, I think. Please, take a look at my last changes in the question. I have added converter and registered it in the config.xml. But I can't use `DefaultFormattingConversionService` - get an error: "... cannt convert UserRoleConverter to StringValueResolver...". Could you tell me how I should register the converter, please. Thanks.